# Wall boundary condition in inviscid flows with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I am trying to duplicate 
https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/navier-stokes-equation.html?product=language
Naiver-Stokes type simulation for a charge current density. 
If I am not wrong, I can use inviscid flow. How can I write wall boundary conditions where the normal velocity is zero?

```
\[CapitalOmega]=RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0.02,0},{0.1,0.0101}],Rectangle[{0,0.0049},{0.02,0.0101}]];
```

```
Show[RegionPlot[\[CapitalOmega], Axes -> False, Frame -> None, 
  ImageSize -> Large], 
 VectorPlot[Evaluate[{1, 0}], {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
  Sequence[VectorScale -> Small, VectorStyle -> Red, 
   VectorMarkers -> Placed["Arrow", "Start"], 
   VectorPoints -> Table[{0, y}, {y, 0.005, 0.01, 0.001}]]], 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

```
inflowBC = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 1, v[x, y] == 0}, x == 0];
outflowBC = 
  DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0.5, v[x, y] == 0}, x == 0.1];
wallBC = DirichletCondition[{u[x, y] == 0, v[x, y] == 0}, 
  0 < x < 0.1]; (*This is wrong condition. How can I convert to \
inviscid flow?*)
bcs = {inflowBC, outflowBC, wallBC};
```

```
{uVel, vVel} = NDSolveValue[{
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] + 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] == 0, 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(u\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"0", ",", "1"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] - 
\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(v\), 
TagBox[
RowBox[{"(", 
RowBox[{"1", ",", "0"}], ")"}],
Derivative],
MultilineFunction->None]\)[x, y] == 0, bcs}, {u, 
    v}, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega], 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "InterpolationOrder" -> {u -> 2, v -> 2}, 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00000025}}];
```

Comment: Hi Emrah. You are in 2D. So in that case, v[x,y] is the "normal" velocity along the horizontal wall. Thus half of your wall BC is correct, namely that v[x,y]==0 along the inlet. I guess you don't want u[x,y]=0 there, which is not right for inviscid flow. I suppose you could try setting u[x,y]=1 there, instead? Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the point. Yes, it will be useful to try. Indeed, I also want to try circular shapes. I have to think about more general solution. I know comsol can solve similar systems. The problem does not seem that hard, but may be I am missing some physical points. I will look into potential and stream scalar options, and use Laplacian.

Comment: I had a similar problem recently (in fact, am still working on it). I had good success with both potential and streamfunction formulations (I have been learning as I go along). Note that in potential formulation, you can use Neumann boundary conditions for the velocity normal components at boundaries, where you need them.

Answer (score 3):

When I plotted the OP's self answered question, I saw vertical flow versus the left to right flow that I was expecting.

```
ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
VectorPlot[
 Evaluate@Grad[sol[x, y], {x, y}], {x, y} ∈ Ω]
```

[image: OP Solution]

As @Paul Harrison alluded to in the comments, that simpler formulation may be to use a [`NeumannValue`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html)flux values at the inlet or outlet boundaries.  We will define a NeumannValue flux condition at the inlet and an essential [`DirichletCondition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DirichletCondition.html).  Also, we will recast the equations in coefficient form so material flows from high potential to low potential.  Here is an example workflow.

```
Ω = 
  RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0.02, 0}, {0.1, 0.0101}], 
   Rectangle[{0, 0.0049}, {0.02, 0.0101}]];
pressurePoint = DirichletCondition[phi[x, y] == 0, x == 0.1];
nv = NeumannValue[1, x == 0];
bcs = {pressurePoint};
sol = NDSolveValue[{Inactive[
       Div][{{-1, 0}, {0, -1}}.Inactive[Grad][phi[x, y], {x, y}], {x, 
       y}] == nv, bcs}, phi, {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
   Method -> {"FiniteElement", 
     "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.00000025}}];
vel[x_, y_] := Evaluate@Grad[-sol[x, y], {x, y}]
nvel[x_, y_] := {vel[x, y][[2]], -vel[x, y][[1]]}
Show[ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
  Sequence[PlotRange -> All, Frame -> None, Axes -> None, 
   Contours -> 40, ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
   ContourStyle -> Black]], Graphics[RegionBoundary[Ω]],
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, ImageSize -> Medium]
VectorPlot[vel[x, y], {x, y} ∈ Ω, 
 AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Left to right flow]

Now, the flow is left to right as I initially expected.  We can zoom in on the backward facing step to look at more details of the potential and the flows.

```
roi = RegionIntersection[ 
   Rectangle[{0.015, 0}, {0.025, 0.01}], Ω];
rmfroi = RegionMember[roi];
bounds = RegionBounds[roi];
vals = sol["ValuesOnGrid"];
mesh = sol["ElementMesh"];
coords = mesh["Coordinates"];
subRange = MinMax@Pick[vals, rmfroi[coords]];
legendBar = 
  BarLegend[{"TemperatureMap", subRange}, 50, LegendLayout -> "Row", 
   LegendLabel -> Style["[phi]", Opacity[0.6`]], 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 500, Charting`TickSide -> Left];
options = {PlotRange -> subRange, 
   ColorFunction -> ColorData[{"TemperatureMap", subRange}], 
   ContourStyle -> Opacity[0.1`], ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
   Contours -> 30, AspectRatio -> Automatic,
PlotPoints -> 41, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style["Potential: phi(x,y)", 18], ImageSize -> 500};
Column[{legendBar, 
  ContourPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ roi, Evaluate[options]]}, 
 Spacings -> 0]
VectorPlot[vel[x, y], {x, y} ∈ roi, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Zoomed image]

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution by help of a CFD friend. Using stream function makes much more sense.
Some background.
http://cfd.mace.manchester.ac.uk/twiki/pub/Main/TimCraftNotes_All_Access/fl3-inviscid.pdf

```
\[CapitalOmega] = 
  RegionUnion[Rectangle[{0.02, 0}, {0.1, 0.0101}], 
   Rectangle[{0, 0.0049}, {0.02, 0.0101}]];
inflowBC = 
  DirichletCondition[phi[x, y] == 5.82688 (y - 0.0049)/0.0101, 
   x == 0];
outflowBC = DirichletCondition[phi[x, y] == 3 y/0.0101, x == 0.1];
wallBC1 = DirichletCondition[phi[x, y] == 3, y > 0.007]; 
wallBC2 = DirichletCondition[phi[x, y] == 0, y < 0.007]; 
bcs = {inflowBC, outflowBC, wallBC1, wallBC2};
sol = NDSolveValue[{D[phi[x, y], x, x] + D[phi[x, y], y, y] == 0, 
   bcs}, phi, {x, y} \[Element] \[CapitalOmega]]
```